# How to print a value in the text box from the text file?

Tags: vb6

How to print a value in the text box from the text file?

Using VB 6

While executing the program, text box should show the saved text file value

Need VB 6 code Help.

Comment: Kinda surprising you could find this forum, but not find that answer.  Hmmmm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim line
Open "filename.txt" For Input As #1
Input #1, line
TextBox.Text = line
Close #1
```